# Correct use of IN compared to FOR when describing an action

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

I find it rather odd when someone writes that an item was used "in prediction" of *'X'*, however I don't know whether that is my own preference or it's actually incorrect. Personally,  I think that 'for' is much more appropriate.

To illustrate my point, here is an example of a sentence and how I would correct it:

1 : "Y is a risk factor **in predicting**  cancer recurrence"

2 : "Y is a risk factor **for predicting** cancer recurrence"

I feel both sentences convey the same point, but "in predicting" just sounds weird to me; I prefer option 2. Is there are difference between 1 and 2, or am I just being picky?

Answer (score 1):

2 seems logically incorrect to me. It seems to say that people who have Y are at risk for predicting cancer recurrence. Though, of course, it would be correctly understood anyway.

1 seems logically correct. In the process of predicting cancer recurrence, one treats Y as a risk factor.

But I agree with H Stephen Straight -- you're better off just saying what you mean. Y is a risk factor for cancer recurrence.

Comment: Agree you more than H Stephen Straight - *"for"* sounds really off to me, for the reason you give. I think the underlying "sound" construction would be something like *""Y is a risk factor [to be taken into account] in **the prediction of** cancer recurrence""*, but shorter more direct phrasing is to be preferred anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *risk factor* already implies statistical prediction. Can't you just say *X is a risk factor for the recurrence of cancer*? (For what it's worth *for* sounds better to me than *in*, but both are fully intelligible and acceptable, as far as I know.)

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely wrong about this, as this is just my intuitive feeling, but I suspect that 2 is the correct formulation, and that 1 is actually a corruption of the following:

```
"Y is a risk factor in predictions regarding cancer recurrence"
```

Or as FumbleFingers said,

```
"Y is a risk factor in the prediction of cancer recurrence"
```

It sounds to me like the speaker (or writer) just contracted "prediction of" into "predicting", which is the sort of mistake that gets made all the time when speaking. So, I believe that this is probably a technical mistake, but one made commonly enough that no-one will bat an eyelid if you treat it as correct. Sort of like ending a sentence with a preposition - I know it's wrong, but I still do it all the time! :p

Summary: The answer to your questions are Yes.